# Kernel Connection issue ([SpyderKernelApp] Error Exception in Message handler. Spyder 5.1.5

Tags: python, spyder

When I load up Spyder (even as an administrator) I continuously get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\aaron\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\comms\frontendcomm.py", line 164, in poll_one
    asyncio.run(handler(out_stream, ident, msg))
  File "C:\Users\aaron\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nest_asyncio.py", line 32, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(future)
  File "C:\Users\aaron\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nest_asyncio.py", line 60, in run_until_complete
    f = asyncio.ensure_future(future, loop=self)
  File "C:\Users\aaron\anaconda3\lib\asyncio\tasks.py", line 680, in ensure_future
    raise TypeError('An asyncio.Future, a coroutine or an awaitable is '
TypeError: An asyncio.Future, a coroutine or an awaitable is required
```

When I restart the kernel it goes away but I prefer not to have to do that every time. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) Please open the Anaconda Prompt and run there `conda install ipykernel=5 jupyter_client=6`. That should solve your problem.

Answer (score -1):

In the Tools menu in spyder, select "reset spyder to factory defaults".